# find max and min in reduce function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

how to find max and min value inside reduce function.I can do sum of 'a' and sum of 'b' in the data set  but I can't find the maximum a and the minumum b and add it in the same list

```js
var liste = [
  {"id":1,"a":5,"b":4},
  {"id":1,"a":2,"b":2},
  {"id":1,"a":7,"b":1},
  {"id":1,"a":1,"b":0},
  
  {"id":2,"a":11,"b":5},
  {"id":2,"a":32,"b":75},
  {"id":3,"a":1,"b":1},
  {"id":4,"a":1,"b":1},
  {"id":4,"a":213,"b":1},
  {"id":5,"a":1,"b":1},
  {"id":5,"a":1,"b":1},
]
var max = 0;
let map = liste.reduce((prev, next) => {  
  
    if (next.id in prev) {
       prev[next.id].a += next.a;
       prev[next.id].b += next.b;
       if(next.a > max){
         max = next.a;
         prev[next.id].max = max;
         
       }
    } else {
       prev[next.id] = next;
      
       next.max =max
    }
    return prev;
}, {});
let result = Object.keys(map).map(id => map[id]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is your expected result supposed to look like?

Comment: `reduce` is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Just FWIW, these days `Object.keys(map).map(id => map[id]);` can be written `Object.values(map)`.

Comment: You need `prev[next.id].maxa` and `prev[next.id].minb` properties.

Comment: @NickParsons like this 
 {
    "id": 5,
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2,
    "max": 1,
    "min": 1,
    "global_max":213,
    "global_min":0
  }

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know I can use a tool, but I don't want to do that because the project is built using reduce

Comment: @MustafaDeniz - You're modifying the code anyway. Simplify it by using the right tool for the job (a `for-of` loop). `reduce` is [dramatically overused](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) and difficult to maintain. It's appropriate when the value you're returning from the callback changes each time (`[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b)`), but not when it isn't (it isn't in your case, it's the same object every time).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the question is, there is a list, the elements in this list need to be grouped, the data in the grouping must be collected and the collected data must be compared with the largest 'a' or the smallest 'b' in this list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically do what you're doing, just include max values for `a` and `b` in the entry where you're doing your summing up.

But `reduce` is the wrong tool for this, all you need is a simple `for-of` loop. (You *can* shoehorn it into a `reduce` call, because basically any array manipulation can be shoehorned into a `reduce` call, but it doesn't buy you anything but complexity.) I'd also use a `Map` rather than a blank object for the lookup (but an object works too; when using objects for this, I typically suggest creating ones without prototypes via `Object.create(null)`).

```
const map = new Map();
for (const entry of liste) {
    const {id, a, b} = entry;
    // Do we have an entry for this ID?
    let known = map.get(id);
    if (!known) {
        // No, use this one (note: I would make a copy rather than modifying the original)
        known = entry;
        map.set(id, entry);
        // Initialize its max with the values from this entry
        entry.max_a = a;
        entry.max_b = b;
    } else {
        // Update our max values
        known.max_a = Math.max(known.max_a, a);
        known.max_b = Math.max(known.max_b, b);
        // Add in the current entries to the sum
        known.a += a;
        known.b += b;
    }
}
// Show the result
console.log([...map.values()]);
```

Live Example:

```js
var liste = [
  {"id":1,"a":5,"b":4},
  {"id":1,"a":2,"b":2},
  {"id":1,"a":7,"b":1},
  {"id":1,"a":1,"b":0},
  
  {"id":2,"a":11,"b":5},
  {"id":2,"a":32,"b":75},
  {"id":3,"a":1,"b":1},
  {"id":4,"a":1,"b":1},
  {"id":4,"a":213,"b":1},
  {"id":5,"a":1,"b":1},
  {"id":5,"a":1,"b":1},
]
const map = new Map();
for (const entry of liste) {
    const {id, a, b} = entry;
    // Do we have an entry for this ID?
    let known = map.get(id);
    if (!known) {
        // No, use this one (note: I would make a copy rather than modifying the original)
        known = entry;
        map.set(id, entry);
        // Initialize its max with the values from this entry
        entry.max_a = a;
        entry.max_b = b;
    } else {
        // Update our max values
        known.max_a = Math.max(known.max_a, a);
        known.max_b = Math.max(known.max_b, b);
        // Add in the current entries to the sum
        known.a += a;
        known.b += b;
    }
}
// Show the result
console.log([...map.values()]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: after this code, I can take a loop again and find the maximum value, but the data is too much and the real time can change, so I want to do it in the map or in the reduce.

Comment: i used your codes after added somethings that if(maks<entry.a){ maks = a } entry.global_max_a = maks , the largest element in the list is only in the last element but i can use last that variable , thank you

Comment: @MustafaDeniz - Yeah, it wasn't (isn't :-) ) clear to me what "max" you wanted, but it's easy to adjust the above to whichever max it is. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `id` exists and update the object, otherwise create a new object with the given values and the min and max values.

```js
var liste = [{ id: 1, a: 5, b: 4 }, { id: 1, a: 2, b: 2 }, { id: 1, a: 7, b: 1 }, { id: 1, a: 1, b: 0 }, { id: 2, a: 11, b: 5 }, { id: 2, a: 32, b: 75 }, { id: 3, a: 1, b: 1 }, { id: 4, a: 1, b: 1 }, { id: 4, a: 213, b: 1 }, { id: 5, a: 1, b: 1 }, { id: 5, a: 1, b: 1 }],
    global_min = Infinity,
    global_max = -Infinity,
    map = liste.reduce((r, { id, a, b }) => {
        if (id in r) {
            r[id].a += a;
            r[id].b += b;
            r[id].max = Math.max(r[id].max, a);
            r[id].min = Math.min(r[id].min, b);
        } else {
            r[id] = { id, a, b, max: a, min: b };
        }
        global_max = Math.max(global_max, a);
        global_min = Math.min(global_min, b);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Object.values(map).map(o => Object.assign(o, { global_max, global_min }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks  for your commet not exactly what I want, I want to print the biggest variable globally in all its elements. for example, the biggest element here is 213 {
     "id": 5,
     "a": 2,
     "b": 2,
     "max": 1,
     "min": 1,
     "Global_max": 213
   }

Comment: where is th global coming from? should it be in any result object?

Comment: compare 'a' val in all objects